# Getting video file id from its path?

Tags: android, mediastore

I am using below provided code to get video file id from its path . but it is throwing Exception.how can i get the video file id from its path.

```
private long getVideoIdFromFilePath(String filePath,
        ContentResolver contentResolver) {


    long videoId;
    //Log.d(TAG,"Loading file " + filePath);

            // This returns us content://media/external/videos/media (or something like that)
            // I pass in "external" because that's the MediaStore's name for the external
            // storage on my device (the other possibility is "internal")
    Uri videosUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri("internal");

   // Log.d(TAG,"videosUri = " + videosUri.toString());

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID};

    // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(videosUri, projection, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

    //Log.d(TAG,"Video ID is " + videoId);
    cursor.close();
    return videoId;
}
```

05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407): com.pcs.sliderringtineproj fatal error : Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:147)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:85)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getLong(CursorWrapper.java:106)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at net.video.bunty.cutvideopreview.CutVideoPreviewActivity.getVideoIdFromFilePath(CutVideoPreviewActivity.java:237)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at net.video.bunty.cutvideopreview.CutVideoPreviewActivity.access$0(CutVideoPreviewActivity.java:216)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at net.video.bunty.cutvideopreview.CutVideoPreviewActivity$1.surfaceCreated(CutVideoPreviewActivity.java:76)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:662)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:90)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:195)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2197)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
05-04 19:45:34.089: E/ACRA(24407):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: There is no guaranteed way of doing this conversion. Beyond that, you would need to post the Java stack trace for us to help you with your exception.

Comment: It throws CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

> It throws CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Your `query()` is returning a `Cursor` with no rows, and as a result `moveToFirst()` will not work.

Either you need to:

- Check the `Cursor` to see if it has rows via `getCount()` and handle the case where your query returns no results, or
- Don't do any of this, as there is no requirement that there be some way to convert some "filePath" to a video ID. If you want video IDs, retrieve the videos themselves from the `MediaStore` and get their IDs along the way.